# Apache Kafka, NotLeaderOrFollowerException when sending message

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Trying to run Apache Kafka in docker containers, using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
    - /home/vagrant/myapp/runtime.local/volumes/zookeeper/01/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
    - /home/vagrant/myapp/runtime.local/volumes/zookeeper/01/log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    ports:
    - 2181:2181
  
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - 29092:29092
    - 9092:9092
    volumes:
    - /home/vagrant/myapp/runtime.local/volumes/kafka/01/data:/var/lib/kafka/data 
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M
```

It seems that I can create a topic

```
docker exec -it kafka kafka-topics --create --topic test --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --if-not-exists --zookeeper zookeeper:2181
Created topic test.
```

But when I try to send a message via kafka-console-producer I got the following error:

```
docker exec -it kafka kafka-console-producer --topic test --bootstrap-server kafka:9092
>My first message
>[2021-07-14 15:39:21,010] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 4 on topic-partition test-2, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,011] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,112] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 6 on topic-partition test-2, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,112] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,643] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 8 on topic-partition test-2, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: NOT_LEADER_OR_FOLLOWER (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,643] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,751] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 3 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.
[2021-07-14 15:39:21,753] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition test-2 due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderOrFollowerException: For requests intended only for the leader, this error indicates that the broker is not the current leader. For requests intended for any replica, this error indicates that the broker is not a replica of the topic partition.. Going to request metadata update now (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

The following is a partial stack trace in the kafka container:

```
[2021-07-14 15:39:12,232] ERROR [Broker id=1] Error while processing LeaderAndIsr request correlationId 1 received from controller 1 epoch 1 for partition test-1 (state.change.logger)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:1002)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:124)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex$.$anonfun$forOffset$1(LazyIndex.scala:106)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex.$anonfun$get$1(LazyIndex.scala:63)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex.get(LazyIndex.scala:60)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.offsetIndex(LogSegment.scala:64)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.readNextOffset(LogSegment.scala:456)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$recoverLog$6(Log.scala:921)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.scala:17)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at kafka.log.Log.recoverLog(Log.scala:921)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$loadSegments$3(Log.scala:801)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.scala:17)
        at kafka.log.Log.retryOnOffsetOverflow(Log.scala:2465)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:801)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:328)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2601)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1(LogManager.scala:830)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:783)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLog(Partition.scala:344)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLogIfNotExists(Partition.scala:324)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$makeLeader$1(Partition.scala:564)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:548)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$makeLeaders$5(ReplicaManager.scala:1568)
        at kafka.utils.Implicits$MapExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$forKeyValue$1(Implicits.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$Node.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:633)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:499)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1566)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1411)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:258)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:171)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't use `:latest` tag. I don't think these versions are maintained - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml or https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: I tried to replace `:latest` with version number `:6.2.0`, but I have the same results.

Comment: 1) What happens when you remove the volume mount? 2) What if you use the bitnami containers I linked to?

Comment: If I remove the volume mounts the problem stops occurring, thanks. By the way, the same behaviour occurs with the bitnami containers.

Comment: After some experiments, I found out that the problem was related to the very specific fact that my containers are runnnig inside a Vagrant virtual machine, and the local volume folders to which I map my /var/lib... folders are synced with the host (Windows 10) machine. As written in my previous comment, the problem disappears when I remove the volume mapping or also if I map to folders in the vm which are not synced with the host machine.
Thanks @OneCricketeer for the suggestion on removing the volume mounts.